# What is the difference between "breathe" and "blow"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between breathe and blow?

The King James Version

Jn.3:8
The wind **bloweth** where it listeth, and thou hearest the sound thereof, but canst not tell whence it cometh

Wycliffe's Bible
Jn.3:8

[image]

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ordinarily only animals breathe. _Blow_ is more general, and humans and wind can both blow, but _blow_ refers to a volitional action if it has a human subject.

Comment: It is unclear where breath comes in. Is this a matter of judging the translation of Greek into Middle English? It would really help if you have the text in both languages for any question (instead of a picture of the script; unfortunately I find it very difficult to read).

Comment: @Mitch We do, though, say "a breath of wind", particularly in its negative sense "not a breath of wind" to speak about very gentle breezes.

Comment: @BoldBen Sure, the two words have something to do with each other, but there's nothing in the KJV or quote that refers to breath at all, so I'm wondering what the motivation is for asking about it. Is it in other translations? (as aan AmE speaker I actually haven't heard that idiom)

Comment: Not relevant to this Bible passage, but since the question asked more generally for the difference: "Breathe" refers to both inhaling and exhaling. "Blow" refers only to exhaling and implies somewhat forceful exhaling.

Comment: @Mitch Perhaps it's a maritime expression that's been absorbed into Br English, a sailing vessel would be becalmed if there was "not a breath of wind". I don't know what part of the US you come from but I'd be surprised if the expression was unknown in coastal New England and other areas with a long history of sailing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the Greek word πνευμα (*pnevma*, from which the English word "pneumatic" is derived, meaning "operated by pressured air") and the Hebrew word "רוח" can mean "wind" and "spirit."

The Greek original goes like this:

> τὸ πνεῦμα ὅπου θέλει πνεῖ καὶ τὴν φωνὴν αὐτοῦ ἀκούεις ἀλλ' οὐκ οἶδας
>   πόθεν ἔρχεται καὶ ποῦ ὑπάγει· οὕτως ἐστὶν πᾶς ὁ γεγεννημένος ἐκ τοῦ
>   πνεύματος

Note that the words "πνεῦμα" (pnev-ma, wind) and "πνεῖ" (pney, to blow) have the same root. "The wind wyndeth."

There is no verb form of "wind" (as a natural phenomenon) in the English language. It is therefore up to the translator to substitute any word that fits the meaning. Both "breathe" and "blow" are good, although technically "blow" is better, because "breathe" may be needlessly poetic.